# VHDL Casting Error

Tags: casting, vhdl, typesetting

I'm quite stumped for the past several days I've been trying to solve a casting error inside my **VHDL**.  My code is attached below.

It will evaluate the if statement properly but will not assign the new value to the min or max variables.  I know this as I commented out and tested different aspects of the function.

**FYI**.  The type `t_battery_data`, contains an array of `std_logic_vectors(15 downto 0)` that are the voltages I'm comparing in the function below.

I'm not sure why it's performing this way.  About all I could find in my searching online was to include the, `ieee.numeric_std` library which I have done.

Still stumped.  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

```
function cell_delta_voltage_counts(
    bat_data: t_battery_data
) return integer is

    constant POS_INFINITY: integer:= 2 ** 16 - 1;
    constant NEG_INFINITY: integer:= 0;

    variable min: integer range 0 to 2 ** 16 - 1:= POS_INFINITY-5;
    variable max: integer range 0 to 2 ** 16 - 1:= NEG_INFINITY;

begin

    for i in 0 to NUM_CELLS-1 loop

        if (to_integer(unsigned(bat_data.cell_readings(i).voltage)) < min) then
            min := to_integer(unsigned(bat_data.cell_readings(i).voltage));
        end if;

        if (to_integer(unsigned(bat_data.cell_readings(i).voltage)) > max) then
            max := to_integer(unsigned(bat_data.cell_readings(i).voltage));
        end if;

    end loop;

    return max - min;

end function cell_delta_voltage_counts;
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't use a lot of functions, but IIRC if you expect min and max to 'remember' their state between calls, you need to declare them outside the function and declare the function as impure:

```
variable min: integer range 0 to 2 ** 16 - 1:= POS_INFINITY-5;
variable max: integer range 0 to 2 ** 16 - 1:= NEG_INFINITY;

impure function cell_delta_voltage_counts(
...
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't see anything wrong here. I tried your code and it works for me in Modelsim DE 10.1c. What simulator are you using?

Here's the code I used when trying your function:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity test is
end entity;

architecture sim of test is

   constant NUM_CELLS : integer := 2;

   type t_reading is record
      voltage : std_logic_vector(15 downto 0);
   end record t_reading;

   type t_readings is array(natural range <>) of t_reading;

   type t_battery_data is record
      cell_readings : t_readings(0 to NUM_CELLS-1);
   end record t_battery_data;

   function cell_delta_voltage_counts(
     (...)
   end function cell_delta_voltage_counts;
begin

   process
      variable v_battery_data : t_battery_data;
      variable v_result : integer := 0;
   begin
      v_battery_data.cell_readings(0).voltage := x"000a";
      v_battery_data.cell_readings(1).voltage := x"001a";

      v_result := cell_delta_voltage_counts(v_battery_data);
      report "result: " & integer'image(v_result);

      wait;
   end process;

end architecture;
```

I used your function exactly as you posted it. The output of simulation is "result: 16" as expected.